# Discrete point inside a polygon formed by set of vertices

Tags: optimization, modeling, constraint, constraint-programming, polyhedra

I am working on a problem where I have a `set of 2D vertices` and a `test point`. I want to chek whether the test point lies inside the polygon formed by the set of given vertices. I am trying to model this problem using **discrete optimization**.

Naturally, this lies under [point-in-polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon#:%7E:text=One%20simple%20way%20of%20finding,an%20even%20number%20of%20times.) problem and I tried to implement a model for the Ray casting algorithm for my discrete problem. It seems a bit difficult to model and program it as I ran into some division issues.(You can look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77194708/or-tools-sat-ray-tracing-algorithm-and-toggle-a-boolean) for the model and the issue). There is a big discussion about the method in [this stack-post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2922778/13720573)

**My Question:**

*1. Is there any other way in discrete optimization modeling to check if a test point lies inside the set of vertices?*

*2. Does the Ray-casting algorithm fit best when we model it in Integer programming format?*

This problem is kinda of stressing me out. Can anyone suggest me some other method that we can model as a constraint model I am using a constrained programming method **hence strictly integers only**

Any help will be really appreciated :)

Comment: I don't have time for a detailed answer right now. One way is to decompose your polygon into convex polygons. Then write the edges of the polygons as equations of the form $ax + by + c = 0$ and compute the relative distance from your point to each edge with linear constraints. There must be at least one convex polygon for which all these distances are negative for the point to lie inside the polygon.

Comment: Is your polygon convex? Is it in order, counter-clockwise?

Comment: @fontanf thanks a lot for the input but is there any name for this method? And how would I find a, b and c in the equation? Will you please elaborate when you get some time? I will be greatful

Comment: @Brannon hello, Yeah polygon is convex, and the points are unordered. Do you have any idea regarding such scenarios?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4779400/discrete-point-inside-a-polygon-formed-by-set-of-vertices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can test whether a point $(x,y)$ appears inside a convex polygon with vertices $(x_i,y_i)$ by solving a linear programming problem (with no objective):
\begin{align}
\sum_i \lambda_i &= 1 \\
\sum_i x_i \lambda_i &= x \\
\sum_i y_i \lambda_i &= y \\
\lambda_i &\ge 0 &&\text{for all $i$}
\end{align}
The idea is to express $(x,y)$ as a convex combination of the vertices.
If the problem is feasible, the point appears inside the polygon.  If infeasible, it doesn't.

---

Note that the $\lambda_i$ are continuous variables. If your solver requires integer variables, you can approximate $\lambda_i$ as $p_i/q$, where $p_i$ and $q$ are integer variables, and clear the denominators:
\begin{align}
\sum_i p_i &= q \\
\sum_i x_i p_i &= x q \\
\sum_i y_i p_i &= y q \\
p_i &\ge 0 &&\text{for all $i$} \\
q &\ge 1 
\end{align}

Comment: thanks for your answer. Really appreciate it. But the thing is I am working in Constraint Satisfaction Programming where the variables can only take Integer values. Here "lambda" takes float value and SAT problems does not support such floating point variables. How can I use you advise for Integer only variables? Can you please help me with that?

Comment: @KenAdams I updated my answer just now.

Comment: thanks for the update. It looks pretty nice. I have one doubt, how will be know that what values will "p" and "q" will take? I have to define domains for both of these. I assume it will be positive. But how will I know the domain? Also, please correct me if I am wrong, If Sum of all "p_i" equals "q" then the point lies inside the polygon right?

Comment: I imposed lower bounds on $p_i$ and $q$.  If your SAT solver also requires finite upper bounds, you will need to determine those yourself.  The point lies within the polygon if and only if *all* the constraints can be satisfied simultaneously.

Comment: Alright thanks: I got it method now.

Comment: I can't imagine that finding rational numbers as p/q will be very efficient for many solvers?

Comment: Dear @RobPratt, would you please, what actually are $p_{i}$ and $q$ purposed to be?

Comment: @RobPratt I implemented your answers in a program. This point in a polygon is one part of a whole project I am working on. The "x" and "y" are not fixed in my case. They are decision variables and value of those are based on all the constrained and point in a polygon is one of the constraints. Can you advice me how to use your formulation in this scenario? I implemented this in my model and I do not get any solution but this part works fine saparately and even my model works fine saparately. Your advice will be helpful :)

Comment: @A.Omidi The integer variables $p_i$ and $q$ are the numerator and denominator of a rational approximation of the continuous variable $\lambda_i$.

Comment: @KenAdams Both formulations still apply if $x$ and $y$ are variables. The second formulation becomes nonlinear because of the products $x q$ and $y q$.

Comment: @RobPratt, thanks so much.

Comment: @RobPratt thanks for the info. But I could not find any example of formulations where x and y are variables. If possible could you direct me to some reference? It will be helpful :)

Comment: @RobPratt no worries, It worked for me :) Thanks a lot!